# SharePoint Designer using Dynamics CRM services as an external data source

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-services, microsoft-dynamics-crm, wsdl

I want to use Dynamics CRM services as a data source for SharePoint 2010. 
I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010 for work with SharePoint server.
I tried to follow [this instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-soap-service-as-a-data-source-HA010355752.aspx). And I'm planning to use links shown in Dynamics CRM -> Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources.  But every time I try to connect
to the service it says that my link "did not return a valid description of an XML web service".

Maybe I'm missing something? 
And generally: is it possible?
Will be appreciated for any idea :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know, you can go to MSSQL server and write your SQL query to fetch data from CRM database.
After this, you can use Sharepint designer, and use [Business data connectivity service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx)

Comment: Direct access to the CRM base is not recommended practice. The data should be received from CRM and not from SQL.

Comment: @Nozim where did you read it is not recommended to access via SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to reference SQL views, then you can access via BCS SQL type.

If you really want to use web services then you will need to use Visual Studio 2010 or later, references below:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/OSP309

http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2012/02/20/crm-2011-online-and-sharepoint-2010-integration-through-business-connectivity.aspx